# Laravel - How can I mock/stub a method on a model correctly

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

How can I mock/stub a method on a model correctly (in laravel)? Currently I am trying...

```
$mock = Mockery::spy(Organisation::class);
$mock->shouldReceive('findByCustomerId')->once();
```

and the code under test is

```
use App\Organisation;
...
public function handle()
{
     $org = Organisation::findByCustomerId(1234);
```

However when I run the tests I get an error `Call to undefined method App\Organisation::findByCustomerId()`, which tells me that the class/model is not being mocked correctly, does anyone know where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mockery doesn't automatically overload classes when you create a mock for them (like some other libraries might do). It does support [overloading](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#overloading), but I couldn't figure out how to overload a class with a partial mock.

So it looks like you'll have to use dependency injection to "inject" the mock object into the class that is being tested:

```
class TestedClass
{
    private $organisation;

    public function __construct(Organisation $organisation)
    {
        $this->organisation = $organisation;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $org = $this->organisation->findByCustomerId(1234);
    }
}
```

Laravel with [automatically inject](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container#automatic-injection) the correct object for you. To inject your mock object instead of the `Organization` class you can do something like this in your test:

```
$mock = \Mockery::spy(Organization::class)->makePartial();
$mock->shouldReceive('findByCustomerId')->once();
$this->app->instance(Organization::class, $mock);
```